# Difference between OS injection and Operating system command injection

Tags: code-injection

Can someone explain to me the differences between OS injection an Operating system command injection?

My understanding is that both techniques take advantage of poor input validation.

My doubt is: does OS injection stand for Operating system injection?

Suppose a certain web site is vulnerable to user's supplied input.

So after some testing I'm able to get information about:

- underlying operating system
- type of server installed

Let's say we have Linux and Apache server.

Through an intercepting software which enables me to interact with the vulnerable site through GET requests (I mean I can modify GET parameters before they are sent) I then succeed in injecting ";ls"

Right, the site is vulnerable since I can see there are files.

So what I did is taking advantage of some bug in order to get access to the underlying operating system.

Is this an example of Os? Or I'd better call it Operating system command injection?

What would an example of Os be?

Sorry for my trivial question.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

They probably mean the same thing. Where did you come across these terms?

Comment: top ten OWASP..thanks for your reply..so you think they are the same? Here's the link for OS injection https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OS_Injection and here you can find details about OS command injection https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OS_Command_Injection

Comment: Based on those descriptions, i'd say they were the same thing. Furthermore, that website looks to be very poorly edited; it doesn't strike me as very reliable. A better source is probably the [Common Weakness Enumeration](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/index.html), which has an entry for [OS Command Injection](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/78.html), and no separate entry for anything called "OS injection".